# 3rd Party Google Drive app that logs into and syncs multiple accounts. (windows)

Tags: google-drive

I am looking for some kind of 3rd Party Tray Icon App for windows that can log into multiple Google Drive Accounts and sync files to them. So I could have 3 folders on my HDrive and have them all synced to three different google drive accounts.

I found an app called inSyncHQ that was exactly this, but the "free" trail was time limited to 16 days and then had a hefty price tag at 30USD per google drive account.

Dose anyone know an alternative application for windows with this same functionality that is either a reasonable price or cheaper? If it can also log into multiple dropbox accounts that would be awesome, though google drive is the priority.

Just to be clear, the goal is to have once application handling the sync that can log into more than one google account. Then set up syncing to google drive to those accounts. Allowing me to have, for example, 3 folders synced to 3 different accounts.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wrote a sync tool that was doing this, but unfortunately it relies on a gateway that does not exist anymore :-/